# Moving a subfolder to a different parentfolder in python

Tags: python, move, subdirectory, shutil

Hi After 2 hours of googling and searching I am failing to find, or build a simple piece of code for the following setup:

3 folders, 2 files:

```
/home/folderA/text2.txt
/home/folderB/
/home/folderB/folder1
/home/folderB/text1.txt
```

**Moving the "Unknown" content of folderB to folderA.**

All the attempts at solving this issue are either deemed too trivial and redirected to "look up shutil." or yielding half a page of code for a specific setup with different demands, rendering it impossible for my miserable pythonskills to develop a sufficient (elegant) result.

In python I have a procedure to identify the existence of folderB, but its contents are unknown and varying to me. In light of full disclosure; here is my XYproblem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from glob import glob
path1 =glob('*')
path2 = glob('*/*/')
print path1
print path2
print len(path2)
a = len(path2)

for i in range(0,a):
  print len(path2[i]), path2[i], path2[i][len(path2[i])-2]
  print(path2[i][len(path2[i])-2].isdigit())
  if path2[i][len(path2[i])-3]==" " and path2[i][len(path2[i])-2].isdigit():
    print('yay')
    newpath =path2[i][:len(path2[i])-2]+"0"+path2[i][(len(path2[i])-2):]
    print(newpath)
    import os
    print(os.path.isdir(newpath))
    if os.path.isdir(newpath): #if it is true, the new folder with the " 0n" already exists
      import shutil
      newpath0=path2[i]+ '*/'
      print(newpath0, "headsup", newpath)
      shutil.copy(newpath0,newpath)
    #shutil.move(
```

But for the sake of those who seek an efficient, simple solution to this problem please keep it to the simplified, and hypothetical case of "folderX" :)

-edit-

Because the folderA indeed already exists, and has the same (potential) hierarchy as folderB. That is why

```
shutil.rmtree('folderA')
```

is not an option; folderA should remain intact.

So, ironically, temporarily removing the contents of folderA to put the contents of folderB in it, yields essentially the exact same problem as I am trying to solve.

-edit2-
Thanks for the effort, I keep on getting:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

at the

```
def mv(from_folder, to_folder)
                             ^
```

Now I appologize for my exceptional level of retardedness but I currently lack the clarity to comprehend how you envisioned your solution;

So after looking up the def mv(.. function I came to the conclusion that you might mean that from_folder should be replaced by a string which contains folderB.

So I tried 2 options:

1. your original
2. defining:

`stringA='folderA', stringB=folderB`

and substituting `from_folder` with `stringB` and `to_folder` with `stringA` in the first 3 rows of your code.

Both yield the same error.

*Note import os and import shutil have already been performed within the active if loop. Just to ensure that was the not causing the problem, I also tried it with an the given explicit import os and import shutil immediatly above def..

the code I so far have hence looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from glob import glob
path1 =glob('*')
path2 = glob('*/*/')
#print path1
#print path2
#print len(path2)
a = len(path2)

for i in range(0,a):
  #print len(path2[i]), path2[i], path2[i][len(path2[i])-2]
  #print(path2[i][len(path2[i])-2].isdigit())
  if path2[i][len(path2[i])-3]==" " and path2[i][len(path2[i])-2].isdigit():
    #print('yay')
    newpath =path2[i][:len(path2[i])-2]+"0"+path2[i][(len(path2[i])-2):]
    #print(newpath)
    import os
    #print(os.path.isdir(newpath))
    if os.path.isdir(newpath): #if it is true, the new folder with the " 0n" already exists
      import shutil
      newpath0=path2[i]+ '*/'
      #print(newpath0, "hier", newpath, ' en path2[i] ', path2[i])
      #shutil.copy(newpath0,newpath)
      #from here chose from_folder = path2[i] and to_folder=newpath
      stringb = path2[i]
      stringa = newpath
      print(stringb,' ', stringa)
      print('reached')
      def mv(stringb, stringa):
    root_src_dir = stringb
    print('reached')
        root_dst_dir = stringa

    for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_src_dir):
      dst_dir = src_dir.replace(root_src_dir, root_dst_dir)
      if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
        os.mkdir(dst_dir)
      for file_ in files:
        src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, file_)
        dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_)
        if os.path.exists(dst_file):
          os.remove(dst_file)
        shutil.move(src_file, dst_dir)
```

But it refuses to print the second "reached", or in other words, it does not define

Answer (score 0):

```
import shutil

shutil.copytree('folderB', 'folderA')
```

Just make sure `folderA` doesn't exist before running the command.

If for some reason the folder already exists beforehand and you have no control over that, just do

```
shutil.rmtree('folderA')
shutil.copytree('folderB', 'folderA')
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, it made me realize that my question was answerable without solving the intrinsic problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os
import shutil

def mv(from_folder, to_folder):
    root_src_dir = from_folder
    root_dst_dir = to_folder

    for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_src_dir):
        dst_dir = src_dir.replace(root_src_dir, root_dst_dir)
        if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
            os.mkdir(dst_dir)
        for file_ in files:
            src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, file_)
            dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_)
            if os.path.exists(dst_file):
                os.remove(dst_file)
            shutil.move(src_file, dst_dir)
```

Then

```
>>>mv('path/to/folderB', 'path/to/folderA')
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I keep on getting:

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax` 

at the 
def mv(from_folder, to_folder)
                                        ^
Now I appologize for my exceptional level of retardedness but I currently lack the clarity to comprehend how you envisioned your solution;

So after looking up the def mv(.. function I came to the conclusion that you might mean that from_folder should be replaced by a string which contains folderB.

So I tried 2 options:
-your original
-defining `stringA='folderA', stringB=folderB` and substituting from_folder with stringB..
Both yield same

Comment: There's missing colon at the end of that line `def mv(from_folder, to_folder):`

Comment: Hero, going for a retry now, did not occur to me, should have though!

Comment: I've added the colon  But it will not print the 2nd 'reached' or in other words it does not engage in/after def mv(..

On a totally unrelated sidenote, I program within a virtual machin in kwrite, and copy pasting inbetween the environments somehow keeps "messing" up the indents at random positions, for example in my 2nd example code in the original post at the line right under def mv. Drives me slowly crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help! I've tried a different approach;

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from glob import glob
path1 =glob('*')
path2 = glob('*/*/')
print path1
print('hi')
#print path2
#print len(path2)
a = len(path2)

for i in range(0,a):
  #print len(path2[i]), path2[i], path2[i][len(path2[i])-2]
  #print(path2[i][len(path2[i])-2].isdigit())
  if path2[i][len(path2[i])-3]==" " and path2[i][len(path2[i])-2].isdigit():
    #print('yay')
    newpath =path2[i][:len(path2[i])-2]+"0"+path2[i][(len(path2[i])-2):]
    #print(newpath)
    import os
    #print(os.path.isdir(newpath))
    if os.path.isdir(newpath): #if it is true, the new folder with the " 0n" already exists
      import shutil
      newpath0=path2[i]+ '*/'
      #print(newpath0, "hi", newpath, ' en path2[i] ', path2[i])
      #shutil.copy(newpath0,newpath)
      #from here chose from_folder = path2[i] and to_folder=newpath
      #stringb = path2[i]
      #stringa = newpath
      #print(stringb,' ', stringa)
      print('reached')
      subb = os.listdir(path2[i]) #subb is defined here as a list of all the subfolders and subfiles in folderB
      #print(subb,len(subb))
      print(newpath) #newpath = folderA

      for c in range(0,(len(subb))): #This creates an index running for running through all the entries in subb
    completesubb=range(len(subb)) #This line defines an array which will contain the full path to all the subfolders and subfiles within folderB
    completesubb[c] = path2[i]+subb[c]#here the full path to the subfolders and subfiles within folderB is created,(with 1 sub-file/folder per entry in the array)
    print completesubb[c]
    completesuba=range(len(subb)) #This will not be required
    #move_file(completesubb[c],newpath) #gave an error
    shutil.move(completesubb[c],newpath) #moves everythin inside folderB to inside folderA
```

Now all that is left for me to do is improve the recognizing procedure for "folderA" and folderB but that's another story :) Thnx everyone, as soon as my rep reaches 15 you'll get an automated raise ;)